# Update associative array

Tags: json, powershell

How to properly update a JSON associative array with PowerShell?

I have the following set up:

```bsh
$json = Get-Content $file -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$arr = $json.MyJsonObject

foreach ($entry in $arr) {
    ??? = $entry -replace "UpdateMe", "REPLACEMENT"
}
```

What to fill in instead of `???`?

The JSON looks like this:

```json
{
  "MyJsonObject" : {
      "A": "UpdateMe",
      "B": "UpdateMe"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$arr` is not an associative array (or hashtable in PowerShell terms), but a nested object. To change the values of that object's properties without knowing the property names you need to enumerate the properties and assign the modified value back to them:

```
$json.MyJsonObject.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Value = $_.Value -replace 'UpdateMe', 'REPLACEMENT'
}
```